# Custom error pages for non-existant directory/file Web API (not controllers)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, asp.net-web-api2

I know I can have custom error pages for non existent controllers or wrong routing but how can I show custom error pages if an user tries to download a file that does not exist inside some directory? I can't make it work at all. It's still showing default error page.

Answer (score 3):

This blog post walks you through handling 404 errors in ASP.Net Web API: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/handling-http-404-error-in-asp-net-web-api

> Let's say that you are developing a HTTP RESTful application using ASP.NET Web API framework. In this application you need to handle HTTP 404 errors in a centralized location. From ASP.NET Web API point of you, you need to handle these situations,
>
> - No route matched.
> - Route is matched but no {controller} has been found on route.
> - No type with {controller} name has been found.
> - No matching action method found in the selected controller due to no action method start with the request HTTP method verb or no action method with IActionHttpMethodProviderRoute implemented attribute found or no method with {action} name found or no method with the matching {action} name found.
>
> Now, let create a ErrorController with Handle404 action method. This action method will be used in all of the above cases for sending HTTP 404 response message to the client.

```
public class ErrorController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpHead, HttpOptions, AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Handle404()
    {
        var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = "The requested resource is not found";
        return responseMessage;
    }
}
```

> You can easily change the above action method to send some other specific HTTP 404 error response. If a client of your HTTP service send a request to a resource(uri) and no route matched with this uri on server then you can route the request to the above Handle404 method using a custom route. Put this route at the very bottom of route configuration,

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Error404",
    routeTemplate: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Handle404" }
);
```

> Now you need handle the case when there is no {controller} in the matching route or when there is no type with {controller} name found. You can easily handle this case and route the request to the above Handle404 method using a custom IHttpControllerSelector. Here is the definition of a custom IHttpControllerSelector,

```
public class HttpNotFoundAwareDefaultHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    public HttpNotFoundAwareDefaultHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    : base(configuration)
    {
    }
    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpControllerDescriptor decriptor = null;
        try
        {
            decriptor = base.SelectController(request);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException ex)
        {
            var code = ex.Response.StatusCode;
            if (code != HttpStatusCode.NotFound) throw;
            var routeValues = request.GetRouteData().Values;
            routeValues["controller"] = "Error";
            routeValues["action"] = "Handle404";
            decriptor = base.SelectController(request);
        }
        return decriptor;
    }
}
```

> Next, it is also required to pass the request to the above Handle404 method if no matching action method found in the selected controller due to the reason discussed above. This situation can also be easily handled through a custom IHttpActionSelector. Here is the source of custom IHttpActionSelector,

```
public class HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector : ApiControllerActionSelector
{
    public HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector()
    {
    }

    public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        HttpActionDescriptor decriptor = null;
        try
        {
            decriptor = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException ex)
        {
            var code = ex.Response.StatusCode;
            if (code != HttpStatusCode.NotFound && code != HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed) throw;
            var routeData = controllerContext.RouteData;
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Handle404";
            IHttpController httpController = new ErrorController();
            controllerContext.Controller = httpController;
            controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor(controllerContext.Configuration, "Error", httpController.GetType());
            decriptor = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
        }
        return decriptor;
    }
}
```

> Finally, we need to register the custom IHttpControllerSelector and IHttpActionSelector. Open global.asax.cs file and add these lines,

```
configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new HttpNotFoundAwareDefaultHttpControllerSelector(configuration));
configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector());
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm not looking for. It covers everything but non-existant directory/file errors

Comment: I tried using the above codes in my API application It throws errors like `The type or namespace name 'IHttpControllerSelector' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) The type or namespace name 'IHttpActionSelector' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `
 In Global.asax.cs can you please  help me with this

Comment: as @thiago said, this is not the valid answer for non-existing file or directory. there should a different solution within web.config.

Comment: Just add 'using System.Web.Http.Dispatcher;' and the problem will be solved